# How can I batch delete events from Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have few events in my Calendar that are scheduled weekly at the same time with the same name.

Because of some issues with syncing between Outlook/Hotmail Calendar/Google Calendar these events are no longer repeated events in my GCal but many independent events. Therefore I can't delete a single event using "All following" option. I wan't to delete all the events in series.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here, where I use the API to delete events: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47768/2711

You can adjust that script to check the name of each event, and only delete the events whose names match what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I made [a program in Google Apps Script that can do this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRylapVSejmJJiwzqwFxJvNK7_E__gSM8isaIf-XouU/edit?usp=sharing).

The link is to a Google Spreadsheet that acts as a GUI to a Google Apps Script. The Google Apps Script uses the Calendar API (here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) to perform all the various functions that someone might want to do when editing an event. If you want to see how it works, copy the spreadsheet to your Google Drive and click in the menu "Tools > Script Editor"

Comment: If (when) that link stops working, there is no useful information in this answer.

Comment: Well, I don't expect the link to stop working anytime soon (and by then, Google may have actually introduced a feature to bulk edit events), but I have updated the link with one directly to the program on my Google Drive. This link I guarantee will be up long into the future.

Comment: Still and all, we like our answer to be self-contained. A link is great as a reference, but an answer should have everything a person needs. From our "[answer]" guidance: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: Further, please **do not** use URL shorteners here. They are unnecessary and are all-too-often used to mask spam, phishing links, or Rick Astley.

Comment: Well, although it's a link to a scripted spreadsheet, it has answered the question for me in the most perfect way I could imagine. It's ideal for someone not having the skills to script himself. Very very useful, @dereknatrican!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the google calendar api for bulk operations such as delete: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: How exactly? The link brings me to a general site.

Comment: This addon does the job https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/calendar_toolbox/517631215797