# Delete hundreds of Google Calendar events created by Zapier

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts, zapier

I set up a "Zap" with Zapier that was supposed to create a Calendar event every time I created a new contact. I added "whenever a contact is updated" to the formula and linked it to my contacts and calendar.

Then I went into my contacts and "sorted" them by location and relationship ("Spokane", "South Carolina", "Clients", etc.) Zapier obediently created a new event (a recurring event, no less) for basically every one of my contacts. (or at least the ones that I changed - which was most of them). So now my calendar has hundreds of events (all at 10 pm) that recur every two weeks...!

I know how to delete them and choose "delete all occurrences" but I would rather not "Select event" "Delete event" "Delete all occurrences" several hundred times!

All of these events have the title "Met [First name][Last name]" as the event title and I can search for "Met" and pull them all up on one screen, but I don't see any way to select multiple events or (better) select all.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm heading over to Zapier now to see if I can create a script to help, but I'm not optimistic... also, I'm pretty sure that creating these hundreds of events caused me to reach my "zap limit" at Zapier.

Comment: You can do it with Apps Script, as shown [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47768). If necessary, use search options of [`getEvents` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)) to pinpoint the Zapier-created ones.