# How do I delete multiple recurring events from Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-calendar

To delete multiple events, I used the script in this answer -
 [How to delete all events on many dates all at once but not the whole Calendar in Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19513/how-to-delete-all-events-on-many-dates-all-at-once-but-not-the-whole-calendar-in/47768#47768)

```
var fromDate = new Date(2013,0,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(2013,0,4,0,0,0);
var calendarName = 'My Calendar';

// delete from Jan 1 to end of Jan 4, 2013

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
  var ev = events[i];
  Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
  ev.deleteEvent();
}
```

However, the problem I have is that I have around 50 events per month which are recurring every year (birthdays), so it just goes on and on. How can I delete to make sure the recurring events are deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete not just the particular Event but the Event Series to which it belongs. So, instead of `ev.deleteEvent();` use

```
ev.getEventSeries().deleteEventSeries();
```

This should also work for events that aren't repeated, because the method [`getEventSeries`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getEventSeries()) wraps them in a new EventSeries object.

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
function delete_rec_events()
{
  //take care: Date function starts at 0 for the month (January=0)
  var fromDate = new Date(2018,0,1,0,0,0); //This is January 1, 2018
  var toDate = new Date(2018,0,10,0,0,0);   //This is January 10, 2018 at 00h00'00"

  var calendarName = '<Name of the Calendar>';
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

  for (var i=0; i<events.length;i++)
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log('Checking Event Title === ' + calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle());
    calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).deleteEventSeries();
    Logger.log('Event Deleted'); 
  }
}
```